# Monitor stays blank after switching KVM back to FreeBSD computer

Tags: freebsd

I have FreeBSD 13.1 installed, with integrated Intel graphics (an Intel NUC).  I've tried with and without ACPI video support, with the Intel graphics driver, and with the NVidia graphics driver (it has two cards) - whenever I switch away from the machine to the other via KVM, then switch back, the monitor stays blank.

I can access the machine via SSH so it's still up.  This happens both when I'm using X, and when I've just boot into the console.

Nothing shows up in dmesg.  I haven't found anything related online by searching.  What might be causing this?

Edit to provide information for anyone else experiencing this: the screen also remains blank after turning the monitor off and back on again.  I installed Ubuntu Linux in place of FreeBSD and had the same problem.  Downgrading the NVidia drivers from 5xx to 4xx fixed it on Linux.

```
 psi# cat dmesg.boot | grep -i acpi  
  Features=0xbfebfbff<FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT,PSE36,CLFLUSH,DTS,ACPI,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,SS,HTT,TM,PBE>
ACPI APIC Table: <INTEL NUC11PHB>
acpi0: <INTEL>
Firmware Error (ACPI): Failure creating named object [\134_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20201113/dswload2-480)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20201113/psobject-372)
Firmware Error (ACPI): Failure creating named object [\134_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20201113/dswload2-480)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20201113/psobject-372)
acpi0: Power Button (fixed)
cpu0: <ACPI CPU> on acpi0
hpet0: <High Precision Event Timer> iomem 0xfed00000-0xfed003ff on acpi0
attimer0: <AT timer> port 0x40-0x43,0x50-0x53 irq 0 on acpi0
Timecounter "ACPI-fast" frequency 3579545 Hz quality 900
acpi_timer0: <24-bit timer at 3.579545MHz> port 0x1808-0x180b on acpi0
acpi_ec0: <Embedded Controller: GPE 0x6e> port 0x62,0x66 on acpi0
pcib0: <ACPI Host-PCI bridge> port 0xcf8-0xcff on acpi0
pci0: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib0
pcib1: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 6.0 on pci0
pci1: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib1
pcib2: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 7.0 on pci0
pcib3: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 7.2 on pci0
pcib4: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.0 on pci0
pci2: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib4
pcib5: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.2 on pci0
pci3: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib5
pcib6: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.4 on pci0
pci4: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib6
pcib7: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 29.0 on pci0
pci5: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib7
acpi_button0: <Sleep Button> on acpi0
acpi_button1: <Power Button> on acpi0
acpi_tz0: <Thermal Zone> on acpi0
acpi_syscontainer0: <System Container> on acpi0
acpi_syscontainer1: <System Container> on acpi0
acpi_wmi0: <ACPI-WMI mapping> on acpi0
acpi_wmi0: Embedded MOF found
ACPI: \134AMW0.WQBA: 1 arguments were passed to a non-method ACPI object (Buffer) (20201113/nsarguments-361)
acpi_wmi1: <ACPI-WMI mapping> on acpi0
acpi_wmi1: Embedded MOF found
ACPI: \134_SB.WFDE.WQCC: 1 arguments were passed to a non-method ACPI object (Buffer) (20201113/nsarguments-361)
acpi_wmi2: <ACPI-WMI mapping> on acpi0
acpi_wmi2: Embedded MOF found
ACPI: \134_SB.WFTE.WQCC: 1 arguments were passed to a non-method ACPI object (Buffer) (20201113/nsarguments-361)
acpi_wmi3: <ACPI-WMI mapping> on acpi0
acpi_wmi4: <ACPI-WMI mapping> on acpi0
iicbus0: <Philips I2C bus (ACPI-hinted)> on ig4iic0
iicbus1: <Philips I2C bus (ACPI-hinted)> on ig4iic1
  Features=0xbfebfbff<FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT,PSE36,CLFLUSH,DTS,ACPI,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,SS,HTT,TM,PBE>
ACPI APIC Table: <INTEL NUC11PHB>
acpi0: <INTEL>
Firmware Error (ACPI): Failure creating named object [\134_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20201113/dswload2-480)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20201113/psobject-372)
Firmware Error (ACPI): Failure creating named object [\134_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20201113/dswload2-480)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20201113/psobject-372)
acpi0: Power Button (fixed)
cpu0: <ACPI CPU> on acpi0
hpet0: <High Precision Event Timer> iomem 0xfed00000-0xfed003ff on acpi0
attimer0: <AT timer> port 0x40-0x43,0x50-0x53 irq 0 on acpi0
Timecounter "ACPI-fast" frequency 3579545 Hz quality 900
acpi_timer0: <24-bit timer at 3.579545MHz> port 0x1808-0x180b on acpi0
acpi_ec0: <Embedded Controller: GPE 0x6e> port 0x62,0x66 on acpi0
pcib0: <ACPI Host-PCI bridge> port 0xcf8-0xcff on acpi0
pci0: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib0
pcib1: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 6.0 on pci0
pci1: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib1
pcib2: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 7.0 on pci0
pcib3: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 7.2 on pci0
pcib4: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.0 on pci0
pci2: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib4
pcib5: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.2 on pci0
pci3: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib5
pcib6: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.4 on pci0
pci4: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib6
pcib7: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 29.0 on pci0
pci5: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib7
acpi_button0: <Sleep Button> on acpi0
acpi_button1: <Power Button> on acpi0
acpi_tz0: <Thermal Zone> on acpi0
acpi_syscontainer0: <System Container> on acpi0
acpi_syscontainer1: <System Container> on acpi0
acpi_wmi0: <ACPI-WMI mapping> on acpi0
acpi_wmi0: Embedded MOF found
ACPI: \134AMW0.WQBA: 1 arguments were passed to a non-method ACPI object (Buffer) (20201113/nsarguments-361)
acpi_wmi1: <ACPI-WMI mapping> on acpi0
acpi_wmi1: Embedded MOF found
ACPI: \134_SB.WFDE.WQCC: 1 arguments were passed to a non-method ACPI object (Buffer) (20201113/nsarguments-361)
acpi_wmi2: <ACPI-WMI mapping> on acpi0
acpi_wmi2: Embedded MOF found
ACPI: \134_SB.WFTE.WQCC: 1 arguments were passed to a non-method ACPI object (Buffer) (20201113/nsarguments-361)
acpi_wmi3: <ACPI-WMI mapping> on acpi0
acpi_wmi4: <ACPI-WMI mapping> on acpi0
iicbus0: <Philips I2C bus (ACPI-hinted)> on ig4iic0
iicbus1: <Philips I2C bus (ACPI-hinted)> on ig4iic1
```

===

```
psi# grep -i pci dmesg.boot 
  Features2=0x7ffafbbf<SSE3,PCLMULQDQ,DTES64,MON,DS_CPL,VMX,EST,TM2,SSSE3,SDBG,FMA,CX16,xTPR,PDCM,PCID,SSE4.1,SSE4.2,x2APIC,MOVBE,POPCNT,TSCDLT,AESNI,XSAVE,OSXSAVE,AVX,F16C,RDRAND>
  Structured Extended Features=0xf3bfa7eb<FSGSBASE,TSCADJ,BMI1,AVX2,FDPEXC,SMEP,BMI2,ERMS,INVPCID,NFPUSG,PQE,AVX512F,AVX512DQ,RDSEED,ADX,SMAP,AVX512IFMA,CLFLUSHOPT,CLWB,PROCTRACE,AVX512CD,SHA,AVX512BW,AVX512VL>
pcib0: <ACPI Host-PCI bridge> port 0xcf8-0xcff on acpi0
pci0: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib0
vgapci0: <VGA-compatible display> port 0x4000-0x403f mem 0x6053000000-0x6053ffffff,0x4000000000-0x400fffffff at device 2.0 on pci0
vgapci0: Boot video device
pcib1: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 6.0 on pci0
pci1: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib1
vgapci1: <VGA-compatible display> port 0x3000-0x307f mem 0x6b000000-0x6bffffff,0x6040000000-0x604fffffff,0x6050000000-0x6051ffffff at device 0.0 on pci1
hdac0: <NVIDIA (0x10f9) HDA Controller> mem 0x6c080000-0x6c083fff at device 0.1 on pci1
xhci0: <NVIDIA TU106 USB 3.1 controller> mem 0x6052000000-0x605203ffff,0x6052040000-0x605204ffff at device 0.2 on pci1
pci1: <serial bus> at device 0.3 (no driver attached)
pcib2: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 7.0 on pci0
pcib3: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 7.2 on pci0
xhci1: <Intel Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB controller> mem 0x6054190000-0x605419ffff at device 13.0 on pci0
pci0: <serial bus, USB> at device 13.2 (no driver attached)
pci0: <serial bus, USB> at device 13.3 (no driver attached)
xhci2: <Intel Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 controller> mem 0x6054180000-0x605418ffff at device 20.0 on pci0
pci0: <memory, RAM> at device 20.2 (no driver attached)
pci0: <network> at device 20.3 (no driver attached)
pci0: <serial bus> at device 21.0 (no driver attached)
pci0: <serial bus> at device 21.1 (no driver attached)
pci0: <simple comms> at device 22.0 (no driver attached)
pcib4: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.0 on pci0
pci2: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib4
rtsx0: <2.1e Realtek RTS525A PCIe MMC/SD Card Reader> mem 0x6c600000-0x6c600fff at device 0.0 on pci2
pcib5: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.2 on pci0
pci3: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib5
igc0: <Intel(R) Ethernet Controller I225-LM> mem 0x6c200000-0x6c2fffff,0x6c300000-0x6c303fff at device 0.0 on pci3
pcib6: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.4 on pci0
pci4: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib6
nvme0: <Generic NVMe Device> mem 0x6c500000-0x6c503fff at device 0.0 on pci4
pcib7: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 29.0 on pci0
pci5: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib7
nvme1: <Generic NVMe Device> mem 0x6c400000-0x6c403fff at device 0.0 on pci5
isab0: <PCI-ISA bridge> at device 31.0 on pci0
hdac1: <Intel Tiger Lake HDA Controller> mem 0x60541a8000-0x60541abfff,0x6054000000-0x60540fffff at device 31.3 on pci0
pci0: <serial bus> at device 31.5 (no driver attached)
drmn0: <drmn> on vgapci0
vgapci0: child drmn0 requested pci_enable_io
vgapci0: child drmn0 requested pci_enable_io
iwlwifi0: <iwlwifi> mem 0x60541ac000-0x60541affff at device 20.3 on pci0
ig4iic0: <Intel Tiger Lake-LP I2C Controller-4> at device 21.0 on pci0
ig4iic1: <Intel Tiger Lake-LP I2C Controller-5> at device 21.1 on pci0
ichsmb0: <Intel Tiger Lake SMBus controller> port 0xefa0-0xefbf mem 0x60541b4000-0x60541b40ff at device 31.4 on pci0
pci1: unknown notify 0x2
pci1: unknown notify 0x2
pci1: unknown notify 0x2
pci1: unknown notify 0x2
pci1: unknown notify 0x2
  Features2=0x7ffafbbf<SSE3,PCLMULQDQ,DTES64,MON,DS_CPL,VMX,EST,TM2,SSSE3,SDBG,FMA,CX16,xTPR,PDCM,PCID,SSE4.1,SSE4.2,x2APIC,MOVBE,POPCNT,TSCDLT,AESNI,XSAVE,OSXSAVE,AVX,F16C,RDRAND>
  Structured Extended Features=0xf3bfa7eb<FSGSBASE,TSCADJ,BMI1,AVX2,FDPEXC,SMEP,BMI2,ERMS,INVPCID,NFPUSG,PQE,AVX512F,AVX512DQ,RDSEED,ADX,SMAP,AVX512IFMA,CLFLUSHOPT,CLWB,PROCTRACE,AVX512CD,SHA,AVX512BW,AVX512VL>
pcib0: <ACPI Host-PCI bridge> port 0xcf8-0xcff on acpi0
pci0: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib0
vgapci0: <VGA-compatible display> port 0x4000-0x403f mem 0x6053000000-0x6053ffffff,0x4000000000-0x400fffffff at device 2.0 on pci0
vgapci0: Boot video device
pcib1: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 6.0 on pci0
pci1: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib1
vgapci1: <VGA-compatible display> port 0x3000-0x307f mem 0x6b000000-0x6bffffff,0x6040000000-0x604fffffff,0x6050000000-0x6051ffffff at device 0.0 on pci1
hdac0: <NVIDIA (0x10f9) HDA Controller> mem 0x6c080000-0x6c083fff at device 0.1 on pci1
xhci0: <NVIDIA TU106 USB 3.1 controller> mem 0x6052000000-0x605203ffff,0x6052040000-0x605204ffff at device 0.2 on pci1
pci1: <serial bus> at device 0.3 (no driver attached)
pcib2: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 7.0 on pci0
pcib3: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 7.2 on pci0
xhci1: <Intel Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB controller> mem 0x6054190000-0x605419ffff at device 13.0 on pci0
pci0: <serial bus, USB> at device 13.2 (no driver attached)
pci0: <serial bus, USB> at device 13.3 (no driver attached)
xhci2: <Intel Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 controller> mem 0x6054180000-0x605418ffff at device 20.0 on pci0
pci0: <memory, RAM> at device 20.2 (no driver attached)
pci0: <network> at device 20.3 (no driver attached)
pci0: <serial bus> at device 21.0 (no driver attached)
pci0: <serial bus> at device 21.1 (no driver attached)
pci0: <simple comms> at device 22.0 (no driver attached)
pcib4: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.0 on pci0
pci2: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib4
rtsx0: <2.1e Realtek RTS525A PCIe MMC/SD Card Reader> mem 0x6c600000-0x6c600fff at device 0.0 on pci2
pcib5: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.2 on pci0
pci3: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib5
igc0: <Intel(R) Ethernet Controller I225-LM> mem 0x6c200000-0x6c2fffff,0x6c300000-0x6c303fff at device 0.0 on pci3
pcib6: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.4 on pci0
pci4: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib6
nvme0: <Generic NVMe Device> mem 0x6c500000-0x6c503fff at device 0.0 on pci4
pcib7: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 29.0 on pci0
pci5: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib7
nvme1: <Generic NVMe Device> mem 0x6c400000-0x6c403fff at device 0.0 on pci5
isab0: <PCI-ISA bridge> at device 31.0 on pci0
hdac1: <Intel Tiger Lake HDA Controller> mem 0x60541a8000-0x60541abfff,0x6054000000-0x60540fffff at device 31.3 on pci0
pci0: <serial bus> at device 31.5 (no driver attached)
drmn0: <drmn> on vgapci0
vgapci0: child drmn0 requested pci_enable_io
vgapci0: child drmn0 requested pci_enable_io
iwlwifi0: <iwlwifi> mem 0x60541ac000-0x60541affff at device 20.3 on pci0
ig4iic0: <Intel Tiger Lake-LP I2C Controller-4> at device 21.0 on pci0
ig4iic1: <Intel Tiger Lake-LP I2C Controller-5> at device 21.1 on pci0
ichsmb0: <Intel Tiger Lake SMBus controller> port 0xefa0-0xefbf mem 0x60541b4000-0x60541b40ff at device 31.4 on pci0
```

Comment: Any interesting messages show up in `dmesg` or `/var/log/messages`?

Comment: @JamesRisner Other than this: `pci1: unknown notify 0x2` which I see after switching the KVM, nothing

Comment: That's an Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (acpi) error. Sounds like a bug in FreeBSD that is being triggered by the KVM switch.

Comment: @JamesRisner thanks for the info.  Before I tried disabling ACPI altogether (FreeBSD wouldn't boot), and disabling just "video" ACPI.  Neither solved the problem.  If you have any other suggestions I'd love to hear them.

Comment: It would help if you put the output of `/var/run/dmesg.boot`, at minimum any **cannot register**, **failed to**, **ACPI** and **pci** messages. As it is right now, it is not clear enough to me to try an answer.

Comment: @JamesRisner no `cannot register` or `failed to` in `dmesg.boot`.  I've edited my answer and appended mentions of acpi and pci (case-insensitive)

Comment: It's having significant issues with ACPI support. Do you have the latest Intel NUC firmware/BIOS installed? Can you get into the BIOS and change some setting related to ACPI? What options in the BIOS do you have?

Comment: @JamesRisner I've updated the BIOS and checked out the settings. There are some related to PCIe and display (display emulation) that I've messed with, but nothing helped.  Anyway, thanks for all the input.  I think I'll have to just access this remotely.  BTW there are two video "cards" in this - an Intel one and an Nvidia one.  I've tried both drivers.

Comment: @JamesRisner I've added another note, just in case you're interested.  I had the same issue with Linux, but fixed it with an older driver.